# Broken off fuse in case

Tags: fuse-panel

Tried to remove a 50A fuse in my 2002 Toyota Sienna, but the fuse is broken in the box. I tried wiggling it using the fuse puller but it didn't help. Now the insides are showing and I can't remove the broken fuse. How do I get it out?

Answer (score 4):

In a word: pliers. Seriously, if the fuse is already trashed, grab it with a pair of needle nose pliers however you can get ahold of it and wiggle it out. It may self destruct further in the process, but you should be able to get it down to where it comes out.

Answer (score 2):

If it's one of those large square-ish type fuses with the clear window on top for something like the alternator, it's probably screwed in at the bottom (out of sight). Check out this video (albeit for a Camry) for an idea of what's entailed. It'll be frustrating but totally doable if you take your time.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AutPk47lY9A

If I'm off base, can you post a picture or two of what you're looking at?